# PHP imap_search using UID

Tags: php, email, imap

I'm trying to get all mails which are greater than a specific UID but the criterion is not recognized.

```
imap_search($conn,"UID 107:*", SE_UID);

** Notice: Unknown: Unknown search criterion: UID (errflg=2) in Unknown on line 0
```

I'm currently connected to a gmail account but this will be used to connect
to different email clients.

Comment: I really do not understand why uw c-client cares what the search string is (which is what PHP imap is based around).  However, it doesn't appear to support the UID criterion.  Must you use PHP?

Comment: Yes. Unfortunately I have no choice at the moment. Is there any work around?